# For $A$ a tail event, show that $P(A)=0$ or $1$ by calculating expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am a beginner student in probability theory.
I am having difficulty understanding the following problem:

> Suppose $I_A$ is a random variable on the infinite product probability space,
>    $\Omega = \prod_{j=1}^\infty \Omega_j$, where $(\Omega_j, P_j)$ is a probability space.
>    Suppose changing first $n$ coordinates of $I_A$ does not change the value of $I_A$.
>    Show that $P(A)=0$ or $1$ by calculating $\int_{\Omega_n} \cdots \int_{\Omega_1} I_A dP_1 \cdots dP_n$.
>    and $\int_{\Omega_n} \cdots \int_{\Omega_1} I_{A^c} dP_1 \cdots dP_n$.

I understand that 
 $A$ is a tail event and that the Kolmogorov Zero-One Law gives the desired result; but having trouble how 
 I can see the result through expectations.
 I understand
 $P(A) = \int_{\prod_i \Omega_i} I_A dP$ where $P$ is the unique probability measure on $\Omega$.
 Any hint or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law

Comment: @Math1000 thank you for the reference. I read the article and was able to understand that $A$ is contained in exchangeable sigma algebra. However, I was unable to connect it to the problem at hand.